# jQuery - Remove all classes with similar names

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

Is there any better way to do this?

```
$('element').removeClass('class-1').removeClass('class-2').removeClass('class-3').removeClass('class-5') ...
to .removeClass('class-105')
:)
```

I want to remove all class-(n) classes.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Get the classes of the element, process it as a string, and put it back:

```
$('element').attr(
  'className',
  $('element').attr('className').replace(/\bclass-\d+\b/g, '')
);
```

#### Edit:

The `attr` method has since changed, and it no longer reads properties, so you have to use the attribute name `class` instead of the property name `className`:

```
$('element').attr(
  'class',
  $('element').attr('class').replace(/\bclass-\d+\b/g, '')
);
```

Comment: The selector would be off per element though, I'd write it like this: `$('element').attr('className', function(i, c) { return c.replace(/\bclass-\d+\b/g, ''); });​`

Comment: @Nick Craver: Yes, that would be useful if you need to apply it to seveal elements. :)

Comment: Attribute has to be "class", not "className", e.g. `$('element').attr( 'class',
  $('element').attr('class').replace(/\bclass-\d+\b/g, '')
);`

Comment: @t1gor: The `attr` method has changed since the answer was posted. I edited the answer to include code that works with later versions of jQuery.

Answer (score 12):

Here's a small jQuery plugin I'm using for this purpose:

```
(function($) {
    $.fn.removeClassWild = function(mask) {
        return this.removeClass(function(index, cls) {
            var re = mask.replace(/\*/g, '\\S+');
            return (cls.match(new RegExp('\\b' + re + '', 'g')) || []).join(' ');
        });
    };
})(jQuery);
```

You use it like this:

```
$(...).removeClassWild('class-*');
```

Answer (score 1):

Doing  it in a better way using css selector, `[type*=value]`

```
$(function() {
    var i = 0;
    while( ++i <= 105) {
        $('b').addClass('class-'+ i);
    }
  var clas = '';
  var arey =[]
    $('input[type=button]').click(function() {  
        clas = $('b').attr('class');
        arey = clas.match(/class-\d{1,3}/g);
        $.each(arey, function(i, e) {
            $('b').removeClass(e);      
        });
    });
});
```

**Edit** :

Demo : **http://jsbin.com/opebu4/2**

Comment: This would assume that each element has only one class with `class-`, and that they appear in perfect numerical order in the document. I don't think that's the point of the question.

Comment: @patrick, yes you're right.  is there a better way doing this using the same selector ? I'm just curious to know

Comment: @Nick Cravers answer (in the comment under the Accepted answer) is probably the best way to go, though it requires jQuery 1.4 or later. I'll post an answer that would work for pre-jQuery 1.4.

Comment: Yes, that would seem to work if you have only one element. If there's more than one, you would want to place your code in an `.each()` and operate on each element individually. A little complicated, but should work. :o)

Answer (score 0):

...or you can use a [starts-with selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/) if you know the possible class names you'd like to remove.  The nasty part of the task is the sheer number of classes to look for...

```
$(document).ready(function () {
     var classesOfInterest = '';
     for(var i = 1; i<=105; i++)
        classesOfInterest += ' ' + 'class-' + i;
     alert(classesOfInterest);
     $("[class^='class-']").removeClass(classesOfInterest);
  });
```