# How can I use jQuery to remove a class if I don't know all of the class name?

Tags: jquery

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [jQuery - Remove all classes with similar names](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3692142/jquery-remove-all-classes-with-similar-names)

I have code like this:

```
$targetSpan
    .removeClass('sprite-blank');
```

How can I make this remove any class starting with the word 'sprite-icon' ?

Answer (score 1):

There's no specific way to do this; you have to look at the `className` string and iterate over each class.  You can do this by providing a callback to `.removeClass` although there are other ways:

```
$targetSpan
    .removeClass(function (_, classes) {
        var classes = classes.split(' ');
        var finalClasses = '';
        for (var x = 0; x < classes.length; x++) {
            if (classes[x].indexOf('sprite-blank') >= 0) {
                finalClasses += classes[x] + ' ';
            }
        }
        return finalClasses;
    });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/67BAu/1/

A less verbose way to do this based on the supposed duplicate answer: http://jsfiddle.net/67BAu/3/